# SQL - Joining multiple records to one record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a SQL Server database with the the following tables:

**Client** (ClientID, ClientName)

**SalesAgent** (AgentID, AgentName)

**Item** (ItemID, Description)

**Purchase** (PurchaseID, ClientID, ItemID, Price)

**PurchaseSalesAgent** (PurchaseID, AgentID)

Each purchase is only ever one item to one client but there can have been multiple agents involved. I want to return the following list of columns:

*ClientName, Description, Price, Agents*

Where Agents is the names of all the agents involved in the purchase. Either as a comma separated list or as multiple columns with one agent in each.

I'm looking for a way that's compatible with SQL Server 2000 but I'd also be interested in if there's a better way of doing it in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Returning a variable number of columns is not a good idea.

Comment: Your `Purchase` table doesn't have any reference to the `Item` table.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the ItemID. 

When you say not a good idea, are there any specific reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL 2008, you should use FOR XML PATH('')... something like:

```
select c.clientname, i.description, p.price, 
   stuff((select ', ' + a.AgentName 
    from SalesAgent sa join PurchaseSalesAgent psa on psa.AgentID = sa.AgentID
    where psa.PurchaseID = p.purchaseID
    for xml path('')),1,2,'') as Agents
from client c 
join purchase p on p.clientid = c.clientid
join item i on i.itemid = p.itemid
;
```

In SQL 2000, there's no nice way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you, would have been nice with SQL Server 2000 too but this works great for SQL 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Using Sql Server 2008, you can try

```
DECLARE @Client TABLE (ClientID INT, ClientName VARCHAR(10))

DECLARE @SalesAgent TABLE (AgentID INT, AgentName VARCHAR(10))

DECLARE @Item TABLE (ItemID INT, Description VARCHAR(10))

DECLARE @Purchase TABLE (PurchaseID INT , ClientID INT, ItemID INT, Price FLOAT)

DECLARE @PurchaseSalesAgent TABLE (PurchaseID INT, AgentID INT)


SELECT  c.ClientName,
        i.Description, 
        p.Price     ,
        (
            SELECT  sa.AgentName + ','
            FROM    @SalesAgent sa
            WHERE   sa.AgentID = pa.AgentID
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) Agents
FROm    @Client c INNER JOIN
        @Purchase p ON c.ClientID = p.ClientID INNER JOIN
        @PurchaseSalesAgent pa ON p.PurchaseID = pa.PurchaseID INNER JOIN
        @Item i ON p.ItemID = i.ItemID
```

**EDIT**

I made the assumption that **Purchase TABLE** has a column *ItemID INT* to link to the **Items TABLE**